# How to Match on single digit values in a CSV String

Tags: regex

I am simply needing to locate single digits of Seven, Eight or Nine that exist as a value in a CSV string.  This string can also contain nothing or a single value, and so no commas if it is just a single value.  I need to discover a RegEx Pattern that can match on just 7 or an 8 or a single 9.  NOT 77... not 88 not 78 not 17 and not 97.  Each match is looking for single value entries between each comma.

Currently, I have a Regular Expression that correctly locates the matches in between commas.  However, it is failing to find those same matches when the value being searched is at the Beginning or the End of the string.  Each time I try adding syntax to my RegEx to get it to find single 7s, 8s or 9s at the beginning or end, it then also starts finding non-valid entries within the String between commas such as 77 or 9Trunnion.

`My Sample String: '7,8,9'.`

`My Pattern: (?<=,)[789](?=,)`

Another Sample String: `'15,7,98,0,null,Bad Data,9s,7,4,8'`

Link to Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8fAJEN/1

Screenshot:
[image]

This question was marked as having a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512586/regex-to-match-text-between-commas) however I already reviewed this SO Post prior to creating this question as I could not figure out how to match on just single digit values within the CSV.  My question takes the issue further by asking the question on how next to match on the strings between the commas.  The SO Post marked as a duplicate to THIS question again is NOT a duplicate.  It doesn't go any further on showing how to then match on the string between the commas.  It does correctly show how to match WHOLE STRINGs between commas but that is it.  Begin novice at RegEx I needed more assistance in matching on the Strings within the commas and I could not figure out how.

Pattern in the NOT !Duplicate Post:

```
(?<![^,])[^,]*(?![^,])
```

I've pasted below the Two Patterns provided as solutions to THIS SO Post and they are:

```
(?<=^|,)[789](?=,|$) Provided by @Bohemian and chosen as the Correct Answer

(?:(?<=^)|(?<=,))[789](?:(?=,)|(?=$)) Provided in comments by @Ouroborus
```

Comment: To match against beginning of string or comma: `^|,`. So your pattern would be `(?>=(^|,))[789](?=(,|$))`. (I didn't check this so you may not need the innermost parenthesis.)

Comment: Unfortunately that produces Zero matches when using `(?>=(^|,))[789](?=(,|$))`

Comment: You can nest groups. I think the bar is "alternation" syntax, a separator between choices. See [Alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

Comment: That would be because of a typo. It's supposed to be left angle bracket, not right angle bracket, as in `(?<=(^|,))[789](?=(,|$))`. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hmmm... Unfortunately I'm not able to see any matches with the new Pattern.  I appreciate the effort nonetheless.  If I run the RegEx Debugger via regex101.com it simply shows the search pattern continually looking back.  Here is the link: https://regex101.com/r/BVduaF/1

Comment: Also note that if I use your corrected Pattern `(?<=(^|,))[789](?=(,|$))` ... regex101 states that the Pattern contains errors.

Comment: Bleh, sorry about that. I forgot the choices have to have the same length when used in a lookaround. The `^` pattern is a zero-length match while `,` is a 1-length match so they're incompatible in that situation. But you can rearrange the expression to get the same effect: `(?:(?<=^)|(?<=,))[789](?:(?=,)|(?=$))`.

Comment: It appears as though that did the trick... https://regex101.com/r/LrjPTc/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use look arounds:

```
(?<=^|,)[789](?=,|$)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/zmlQtMDVL7rIqA).

Comment: Your demo shows that this patter ONLY matches the Beginning and End.  I was aiming to obtain Any match of a single 7 or an 8 or a 9 in any field.  These fields are delimited by commas.  My system will consume a single CSV String and so I need to check for the existence of these values.  But since there are many values that also contain a 7 such as 17 I needed to find ONLY single digit entries of 7.  My goal again is to Also Include the missing Begin and End fields in the match criteria since they were missing in my attempt.

Comment: @CodeNovice I thought that's what you wanted due to the highlighted squares. I have edited my answer to match any single 789 value, including at the ends.